# is mongodb hashed index has no performance benefit compared to ascending index?

Tags: mongodb

I heard in somewhere that unlike other dbms' hashed index, MongoDB's hashed index
uses b-tree internally, so there is no performance benefit compared to normal ascending index. I was shocked, but soon I noticed that MongoDB version was 3.4 in that article.

## My Question:

- Is this still true for Mongodb version 6 for now?? or was there an enhancement?
- How do I prove that how hashed index works internally?
- do I have to use other storages (like redis) for better performance?

Comment: Why would you expect performance benefits on a hashed index?

Answer (score 2):

I understand where the confusion comes from, but before I answer your questions there is a more important thing worth noting.

Hashed Indexes in MongoDB were added to serve a specific purpose, efficiently distributing data across shards when using sharding. This is the reason they use a "B tree" structure, so they can effectively use the tree branches as shards.

---

With that out of the way, let's answer your questions:

> Is this still true for Mongodb version 6 for now?? or was there an enhancement?

Yes, this will remain the case as they are designed this way (as explained above).

> How do I prove that how hashed index works internally?

Not sure how to answer that, MongoDB is open source and you can dive into the source code yourself if you wish. Or you can believe me :)

> do I have to use other storages (like redis) for better performance?

This is a very broad question, in general an in memory db like Redis will give better performance over "standard" db's as they have network overhead. However in memory DB's have their own issue's that a "standard" DB does not.

Additionally they usually have less features as they are "simpler".

It will be easier to advice which DB fits your needs if we had a proper description of the problem your trying to solve, the architecture you've designed and the scale of your data.